# How to get Delta from a row HTML string in flutter_quill or how to convert HTML to Delta?

Tags: flutter, quill

How to get Delta from a raw HTML string in flutter_quill or how to convert HTML to Delta?

I get HTML code as string from server and i need to insert it to flutter_quill editor but this library can make a new document only from Delta or JSON (JSON from Delta)

I can't use another editor.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-quill-converter

Convert a HTML string to a Quill delta:

```
const { convertHtmlToDelta } = require('node-quill-converter');
 
let htmlString = '<p>hello, <strong>world</strong></p>';
let delta = convertHtmlToDelta(htmlString);
 
console.log(JSON.stringify(delta); // {"ops":[{"insert":"hello, "},{"insert":"world","attributes":{"bold":true}}]}
```